# Styling the default wordpress search box

Tags: css, wordpress

I can't figure out what's causing the blank space between the submit button and the input area of the searchbox.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DuDq.png

html:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">
<p><input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s"  placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Traži" /></p>
```

css:

```
#searchform {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

header input#s {
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    height: 29px;
    width: 250px;
}

header input:active  {
    border: none;
}

header input.submit {
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: -99999px; 
    background: white url(images/search.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/butuzov/MCtc3/

use font-size:0 for parent element (p in your case) or avoid space between input element

Answer (score 1):

This is one from the most frequently questions, it's very important to have a nice search bar with a good look, 
you did a nice work ,but the best way to create a better search bar is like that, follow me step by step it will helps you a lot, the look you want in a short time  :

1. you create the form tag and inside you create a div with class expl : searchBarContainer
2. inside your div you create an input:text and button don't use input:btn 
   // now you have a form / div / input text and button

   ```
   <form  method="get" action="">
   <div class="searchBarContainer">
       <input type="text" class="searchBox" name="s" id="s"  placeholder="Search" />
       <button class="btn-search">
          <img src="search-icn.png" >
       </button>
   </div>
   ```

[image]

3. now we have the structure and we need just a style for our form it looks ugly right ? of course it is, so :

   ```
   .searchBarContainer {
   border: none;
   height: 2.5rem;
   background-color: #fff;
   border-radius: 2px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 20%;
   max-width: 60%;
   display: flex; /* <===== the most iportant line in this code */
   ```

   }

[image]

in this code dyplay flex all that you need to focus on : 
    **display : flex;** 
    **felx : 1;**

```
.searchBarContainer .searchBox {
    flex : 1; /*  <===== the most iportant line in this code */
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    border: none;

}
```

[image]

5. And last for the button style :

   ```
   .btn-search {
   border: none;
   background-color: #fff;}
   ```

**Final Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
.sidebar.widget-area .widget.widget_search .search-form .search-submit {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 19px;
    background-image: url(assets/images/search.png);
    border: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    right: 0px;
    top: 29px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0px;
    height: 17px;
    width: 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```